# Why is the intercept method not updating ShowSpinner variable after it's been called

Tags: html, angular, angular-http-interceptors

I know the method is being called after each service call from some other part of the code base but each time I step through the code when it's called `ShowSpinner` doesn't seem to update back to `false`.

I have used `ngOnInit()` method to check if I can update ShowSpinner outside of the Intercept method and it does update showSpinner and the changes shows on screen.

Typescript

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-spinnerfork',
  templateUrl: './spinnerfork.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./spinnerfork.component.css']
})
export class SpinnerforkComponent implements HttpInterceptor, OnInit {

  ShowSpinner: boolean = false;
  queue = [];
  delayIn = 500;
  delayOut = 500;
  timerPromise = null;
  timerPromiseHide = null;

  constructor() { }

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler):  Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    this.ShowSpinner = true;
    setTimeout(()=>{this.ShowSpinner = false;}, 3000);
      return next.handle(request);
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.ShowSpinner = true;
    setTimeout(() => {this.ShowSpinner = false}, 10000);
  }
}
```

html

```
<div>
  <span *ngIf="ShowSpinner">
    spinnerfork works!
  </span>
</div>
```

"spinnerfork works!" should disappear off screen after 3 seconds instead of 10 seconds

Comment: Is the `intercept` function called at all?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't show now but I have called console.log( ).

Comment: Could be the `this` context, then. Will it work as an arrow function?

Comment: intercept doesn't get called at all. Check it out. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6pen7g

Comment: A http call has to be made to for intercept to be called

Comment: @SumitParakh here's an update https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wwqxhl

Comment: A component should not implement HttpInterceptor. Create a injectable class for that.

Answer (score 1):

This can not work because the `AppComponent` that acts as the HttpInterceptor is not the same as the component that is displayed.
You register the interceptor in the module like this:

```
providers: [{provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: AppComponent,  multi: true } ]
```

This means that when the application requests HTTP_INTERCEPTORS another instance of the AppComponent is created as a service and acts as the interceptor. Interceptors are meant to be global services that modify HTTP requests and not to modify UI elements. I think you are trying to do something else.

If you want to show the spinner while the request is going on you can implement it very simple like this:

```
ngOnInit(){
  console.log('on init');
  this.ShowSpinner = true; // starts spinner
  this.http.get("https://swapi.co/api/people/1").subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
    }, err => {
      console.log(err);
    },
    () => {
      this.ShowSpinner = false; // when the request completes or fails hide it
    });;
}
```

Here is a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zfxrk4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) with this solution.

If you need to listen to all events and want to get progress information check the [documentation about listening to progress events](https://angular.io/guide/http#listening-to-progress-events).